# how to sort a list of dictionaries based on how many times a value occours

Tags: python

i have a list of dictionaries and i need to know which name has a given value in the same dictionary for the most times

i need to do this with no imported modules

```
[
 {"name": name1, "value": value1}
 {"name": name2, "value": value1}
 {"name": name1, "value": value1}
]
```

for example here if the given value is value1 i would get name1 as a result because it occours 2 times in the same dictionary as name1

note:
value1 could also occour with another name other than name1 so i not only need to know the name it occours with but the name it occours with the most

it is a bit hard to explain i hope someone understands the problem.

have no idea on how to effectively solve this problem

Comment: You are looking for the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) data structure. Please consult the documentation and then [let us know](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) what you implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your request, you are looking for the content of the 'name' key which is repeated the most across the entries where the 'value' key is a particular value. This function does that without imports by:

1. filtered to the items which match your 'value' value
2. counting the occurrences of each 'name' value
3. returning the name with the largest count

```
def f(data, search):
    a = [x['name'] for x in data if x['value'] == search]
    return max([(x,a.count(x)) for x in set(a)], key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Usage:

```
data = [
 {"name": 'name1', "value": 'value1'},
 {"name": 'name2', "value": 'value1'},
 {"name": 'name1', "value": 'value1'},
 {"name": 'name2', "value": 'value2'},
 {"name": 'name2', "value": 'value2'},
 {"name": 'name1', "value": 'value3'}
]

print(f(data,'value1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an auxillary dictionary to keep track of the number of times the value is associated with a specific name.

```
def getNameWithMaxOccur(value):
    b = {} # name as key, number of occurrences as value
    for d in a:
        if d["value"] == value:
            if d["name"] not in b:
                b[d["name"]] = 1
            else:
                b[d["name"]] += 1
    return max(b, key=b.get) # name with max number of occurrences
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative and efficient approach using the [`get()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/get.html) method:

```py
given_value = 'value1'
name_counts = {} 

for d in list_of_dicts:
    if d['value'] == given_value:
        name_counts[d['name']] = name_counts.get(d['name'], 0) + 1

most_common_name = max(name_counts, key=name_counts.get)
print(f"Most occurrence is: {most_common_name}. Count: {name_counts[most_common_name]}")
```

---

```
Most occurrence is: name1. Count: 2
```